# Protractor with selenium grid

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, configuration, protractor, selenium-grid

Could anyone please advice how to setup protractor to run tests remotely ?

My protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
    chromeOnly: true,
    chromeDriver: '../node_modules/.bin/chromedriver',
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 3
    },
    specs: ['../e2e/protractor/spec/*.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        isVerbose: true
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        global.dv = browser.driver;
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    },
    seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/selenium-server/lib/runner/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar',
    baseUrl: 'www.google.com'
};
```

My protractor.json:

```
{
  "options": {
    "configFile": "./config/protractor.conf.js",
    "noColor": false,
    "args": {},
    "webdriverManagerUpdate": true
  },
  "e2e": {
    "options": {
      "keepAlive": false
    }
  },
  "continuous": {
    "options": {
      "keepAlive": true
    }
  }
}
```

For now I am running tests locally from ./config location by command `protractor protractor.conf.js` . 
I have already selenium grid configured with vm's and hosts. Have as well IP address which I'll be using to connect with host.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to setup `seleniumAddress: 'http://<IP>:4444/wd/hub',` inside either protractor.conf.js, or your grunt/gulp runner.

All settings is here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L89

Comment: Thanks, works fine.  Could you please advise somehow how I could set some profiles to run tests locally and remotely ?  For eg. I would like to have command `protractor locally protractor.conf.js` to run tests locally and `protractor remotely protractor conf.js` to run tests remotely.

Comment: You can just update your gruntfile (that protractor.json is from it right?)
With seleniumAddress arg:
`options: {
                        args: {
                            keepAlive: false,
                            browser: 'chrome',
                            seleniumAddress: 'http://IP:4444/wd/hub',`

Comment: `The reference configuration has moved. Please refer to /lib/config.ts` this link is basically 404 now