# Can we run the protractor tests in multiple machines?

Tags: protractor

> Similar to selenium grid, can we run the protractor tests in different machines(not in different browsers) and how?

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010305/protractor-with-selenium-grid

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run if you have protractor **installed** on the machines you have choosen.

The machines should be connected to same network.

Then run the **webdriver-manager start** on the other machines

You need to mention in the config file(conf.js) about the Multi capabilities like browser name, ip address, port id of webdriver

Hope this helps